# Saml_IDP gem not pulling metadata or acceptable_hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, saml-2.0, omniauth, idp

I'm trying to implement SSO via SAML and using my application as both the IdP (routes are based off localhost:3000) and SP (routes based off lvh.me:3000). I used the [saml_idp gem](https://github.com/saml-idp/saml_idp) to set up the IdP and the [omniauth-saml](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml) gem for the SP side.

I can get a request sent to the IdP and a response sent back if I bypass the [validate_saml_request](https://github.com/saml-idp/saml_idp/blob/master/lib/saml_idp/controller.rb) method in the SamlIdpController in the gem. The response I get returns the user's email and first/last name per what I configured in the config/saml_idp.rb file.

I really don't want to bypass the validate_saml_request. When I looked to see why my [request is not being validated](https://github.com/saml-idp/saml_idp/blob/master/lib/saml_idp/request.rb), I see that the logs return '[] compare to lvh.me' and 'No acceptable AssertionConsumerServiceURL, either configure them via config.service_provider.response_hosts or match to your metadata_url_host'.

For SPs, my config/saml_idp.rb file looks like:

```
service_providers = {
  "my-application" => {
    fingerprint: ENV['SAML_CERT_FINGERPRINT'],
    metadata_url: "http://lvh.me:3000/auth/saml/metadata",
    response_hosts: ["lvh.me:3000"]
  },
}
```

I confirmed that the metadata does exist at that metadata_url as well. Not really sure why it's not pulling anything via the [metadata_url or response_hosts](https://github.com/saml-idp/saml_idp/blob/master/lib/saml_idp/service_provider.rb) via the config.

On my SP side, the config/omniauth.rb file looks like:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :saml,
    :assertion_consumer_service_url     => "http://lvh.me:3000/auth/saml/callback",
    :issuer                             => "portal",
    :idp_sso_target_url                 => "http://localhost:3000/saml/auth",
    :idp_sso_target_url_runtime_params  => {:original_request_param => :mapped_idp_param},
    :idp_cert                           => ENV['SAML_CERT'],
    :idp_cert_fingerprint               => ENV['SAML_CERT_FINGERPRINT'],
    :idp_cert_fingerprint_validator     => lambda { |fingerprint| fingerprint },
    :name_identifier_format             => "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

While I was unable to get it working using this piece of configuration in the config/saml_idp.rb file, I only needed to have the IdP interact with one SP and was able to get it working by adjusting what I passed to response_hosts and using another part of the code given in the config file (example below):

```
  config.service_provider.finder = ->(issuer_or_entity_id) do
    {
        fingerprint: ENV['SAML_CERT_FINGERPRINT'],
        metadata_url: "http://lvh.me:3000/saml/metadata",
        response_hosts: ["lvh.me"]
    }
  end
```